# How to resolve "too many re-renders" with callback in functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I have a functional component like

```
function Blurg(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(..);
  
  const callback = (data) => { .. setState(...) }

  somethingExternal.addListener(callback);

  return ...
}
```

where the callback will be called immediately if there is a value present.

(**Edit**: the value will stay, so each time a listener is attached it receives that value immediately.)

But this leads to an error saying "Too many re-renders", because the state is changed, then the functional component is called again (i guess), adding the listener again and so forth.

How to resolve this?

Comment: when does your listener gets called?

Comment: @MWO when data is already present in `somethingExternal` then immediately after adding it as a listener. Otherwise when the data comes available.

And i don't want to go through props, as i want to render this component even in case the data is not available yet.

Kinda like a ReplaySubject from rxjs.

Comment: when data is already present in somethingExternal, how long will it be there? because if it stays you call Blurg on and on to render the new state

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my problem. It stays there. Like a ReplaySubject.

Comment: but what is state? do you set it to data? if so I would setState only if data is unequal state

Comment: Didn't work. I converted the FC to a class extending `Component` and using `componenDidMount()`... works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using a one-time effect like

```
useEffect(() => {
  somethingExternal.addListener(...)
  
  // And as a bonus
  return () => {
     somethingExternal.removeListener(...)
  }
}, []);
```

### Explanation

The second argument of `useEffect` is a list of dependencies, that - when changed - will trigger the effect to be re-evaluated.
Thus, if passed an empty list of dependencies, nothing will change.